# CKeditor does not update text area in  source mode

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I am trying to use CKeditor on my website. I am finding that when in *Source mode* the textarea that has been replaced by the ckeditor is not being updated. I need the textarea to be updated as the code on the page is set to save the textarea content on save.

When in normal mode the text is being updated.

```js
$(document).ready(new function() {
    var editor = CKEDITOR.instances['content-text'];

    if (editor) { editor.destroy(true); }

    CKEDITOR.on('instanceCreated', function(e) {
        e.editor.on('contentDom', function() {
            e.editor.document.on('keyup', function(event) {
                // keyup event in ckeditor
                UpdateTextArea();
            });
        });
    });

    CKEDITOR.replace('content-text');
});

function UpdateTextArea() {

    CKEDITOR.instances['content-text'].updateElement();
}
```

Any help greatly appreciated. This is the first time I've asked a question so sorry if I have missed anything!

Comment: what's with the `new function`, why is `new` necessary?

Comment: It's not necessary. must have left that in. I've just tried removing the "new" but still no joy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was being a bit dumb.

On the onclick event of my input button I just needed to add:

```
function UpdateTextArea() {        
    var editor_data = CKEDITOR.instances['content-text'].getData();
    $('#content-text').html(editor_data);
}
```

Comment: This line solved my problems: `var editor_data = CKEDITOR.instances['content-text'].getData();` . Didn't know you can manually "rip" text content from ckeditor. If i did saw this post a day ago, it would save whole lotta headache. Anyroad, mucho kudos from 2019 :D